# PHP Escape ampersand when printing

Tags: php, string, escaping, echo, ampersand

In my flash website, I use PHP to store a bulk of text retrieved from a Database in the variable `$trunk`, and then through PHP I print `$trunk` and catch it using my flash program.

The problem is, sometimes this bulk of text retrieved from the Database will contain an Ampersand "&", and when using `print "$trunk"` It'll mess up very badly and result in not printing anything at all, which causes errors in the flash program.

Using `mysql_real_escape_string($trunk)` won't work, because that function doesn't escape ampersands, and using `html_entity_decode` didn't do anything at all.

**So, how do I escape Ampersands in strings?**

Comment: what's wrong with `str_replace`?

Comment: You have to use `html_entities`, not `html_entity_decode`. Or `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: str_replace would remove it altogether, I want it to show up in flash, I just don't want it messing everything up. @hindmost I'll try that right away :)

Comment: @hindmost Tried it, it output `Shield &amp; Sword` instead of `Shield & Sword`, so It escaped, but it's still messing things up because of the & at the start of &amp; :(

Comment: Does this mean that the character `&` showing up anywhere in your data messes up your flash? If that is so, I think you should try to fix it in the flash side and not in the PHP side.

Comment: @raidenace No, I mean whenever I try to use the function `print` in PHP, and the variable content has an Ampersand "&", it'll mess up.

Comment: @MaChao - can you tell me what you mean by messing up? Its hard to debug without knowing that

Comment: @raidenace I mean it doesn't print. No variable will print if it contains an ampersand, and I'm looking for a way to fix it.